# How to throttle a loop in php

Tags: php

I have to process a script that consumes a lot of CPU and this is for a bunch of users and depends on the user, so I want to run it once, wait for few seconds, run the next user, etc.

I tried delay but the issue I got is that I never get anything printed in the screen to get info about how the whole process is doing and to get intermediate results.

I have one script in which I plan to do this and then run the other process.

Any hints?

Comment: and where is the script!!

Comment: is this a command line process or served by a web server?

Comment: 1) Show us the script 2) print something on the screen (`echo` in command line scripts, `ob_*` (http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) otherwise. 3) `sleep()`

Comment: `sleep()` & `ob_flush()`

Answer (score 1):

You could base what you need on this:

```
for ($i; $i < 10; $i++) {
    do_something();
    sleep(1); // sleep for a second.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a POSIX compatible ptreads package, which may be useful here. See
https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads